# Pass arguments to a function in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the following example:

```
def fcn_a(x, y):
    return x + y


def fcn_b(x, y):
    return x * y


def fcn_c(x, y):
    return x / y


fcns = [fcn_a, fcn_b, fcn_c]


x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [10, 20, 30]
```

I need to apply the functions in `fcns` to each pair of elements in `x` and `y` in order. Something like this:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(fcns)):
    result.append(fcns[i](x[i], y[i]))

# result == [11, 40, 0.1]
```

How can I accomplish this using a list comprehension?

Comment: Where's the double iteration? You only have one `for` loop, what's the expected output? I think you're describing `[fn(xi, yi) for fn, xi, yi in zip(fcns, x, y)]`.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I'm describing. Put it in an answer let's make it official.

Comment: @JasonStrimpel that is what you should use, the comment with `zip`, but note, your loop is directly translatable into a list comprehension, `[fcns[i](x[i], y[i]) for i in range(len(fcns))]` ... list comprehensions are basically sugar for those exact sort of loops

Comment: by using the zip built-in function you will not have the same behavior as using the `for` loop from the question if `fcns` has more itesm than the length of x or y will hide the IndexError

Comment: I didn't downvote, for the record, or meant to imply that you are dumb. I just thought it would be helpful to point out. It's pretty much a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848829/how-to-map-a-list-of-data-to-a-list-of-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in function `enumerate` with list comprehention:

```
result = [f(x[i], y[i]) for i, f in enumerate(fcns)]
```

output:

```
[11, 40, 0.1]
```